# Error installing Perl package Net-Scp with ppm

Tags: perl, scp

How do I install Net::SCP on Windows? ppm didn't help.

```
C:\>ppm install Net-Scp
Installing package 'Net-Scp'...
Error installing package 'Net-Scp': Could not locate a PPD file for package Net-Scp
```

I cannot do a make to build this Perl module, Thanks in advance for the help.
I use ActiveState Perl version v5.6.1

Comment: Are you able to change Perl versions, or add capability to do make (this *is* possible, but a pain under ActiveState Perl to set up)? Adding the Windows version may help to get more specific answers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perl 5.6 is out of support for many years. Upgrade to 5.16.

http://code.activestate.com/ppm/Net-SCP/

Comment: It takes some time to upgrade to new Perl, in the meantime, what can I use which is similar to scp to copy a file from Windows to Linux machine? Perl script will run on Windows. thanks.